# Google recaptcha image not showing in chrome, but can in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, recaptcha

I am writing PHP website with sign up page.
In signup page, I am using recaptcha google. It will show the images for selecting which images are correct choose. It can show images in firefox but not in chrome. 
Then in chrome, it is defaulted to be OK and valid and can pass through to create account. do you have any hints to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory that Google NoCaptcha Recaptcha will always ask you to select images for verifying.

The questions asked by Google NoCaptcha Recaptcha for verification depends on google's algorithm and not based on the browser.

The working of your website according to me is normal, there is no problem associated.

Comment: Hello I am currently having this same issue. Is there any documentation that states that the images are not always required to be selected as proof? thank you

Comment: https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html

Answer (score 0):

The aim of **Google ReCaptcha V2** (NoCaptcha) is to use less validation to be more userfiendly.

So in the most cases checking "I'm not a robot" checkbox is enough, and you should be happy with this.

Pictures validation will be shown if for ReCaptcha alghoritm the first one failed. In general this additional validation is annoying for users.

**So - it is nothing to worry about if pictures are not shown.**